# Xcode with multiple projects Storyboard reference bundle not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having a difficult time trying to figuring out how to make a  storyboard reference work with storyboard from other project. I'm trying to modularize my App, so I'm creating multiple projects inside Xcode workspace. The point is that at some times, one storyboard from project A may have a reference to a storyboard in project B... I thought that the reason for the 'BUNDLE' option in a storyboard reference is that you could achieve what I've mentioned... I've attached an image that explain better what I'm saying... When I try to run, the app links to the Main.storyboard from Project A instead Main.storyboard from Project B...

I've checked and rechecked to make sure that bundle name is correct... [image: XCode screen]

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: The other bundle specified needs to be part of “this” project;  the bundle is resolved at runtime, not compile time. A bundle is not a project.  Projects typically produce one bundle (the main bundle) but they can produce more.  You could probably do what you are trying by using a custom build step to copy the bundle from the other project into “this” project, but it probably isn’t the right approach

Comment: They are part of the same Workspace...

Comment: A workspace is just an Xcode convenience for working on multiple projects at once. As I said, the bundle is resolved at runtime, long after Xcode has ceased to be involved. You would need to copy the specified bundle from the second project into the output bundle of the first project. Perhaps you intended your second project to be a framework that you include with your first?

Comment: I see, but I think thats the point of project have a bundle name... So you can reference it later...

Comment: Yes, but the bundle needs to be in your app bundle, so you need to take some steps to actually put it there beyond simply having it in another project in your Xcode workspace.  If there was a jpeg image in the second project you wouldn't expect to be able to simply use it in your first project?   Putting a value in the bundle field in the storyboard reference tells iOS where to look at runtime.  It doesn't tell Xcode to do anything at build time.

Comment: Hum... I see, is there a way to "link" a project to a bundle? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156227/discussion-between-paulw11-and-cleversou).

Answer (score 1):

First give an id to the reference screen.

second write the storyboard referans add Reference id

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, mate... But still doesn't work... :'(

Answer (score 0):

The bundle name in the StoryBoard reference is the bundle identifier of the FrameWork/Project that contain your reference story board. For example: com.chozinul.CustomUI

Answer (score 0):

Use storyboard name and push controller will viewcontroller identifiers